How do I paste the return value of a function in a cell into a textbox in Excel vba?
This is my Reproducible code : I need to debug.
Sub Macro22()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Range("M4").Copy
    Sheets("Service Application Paper").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 21")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 21")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
End Sub

I want to paste the function return value in "M4" of Sheet1 into Textbox 21 of Sheet 'Serive Application Paper'
I have to put it in the text box.
Thank you.

Besides your question: you may have a look onto How to avoid using select

Not so clear what you try doing. At least, for me. Do you have a UDF (User Defined Function) which returns in a cell and you want when the returned formula value is changed, automatically the code to copy the respective value in "TextBox 21"? Or you want to copy it whenever you run the code? In such a case it does not matter if the respective value is the result of the function... Or what? It would be better to edit your question and try better explaining (in words) what you try doing, please.

Try this way:
Sub ValueToTB()
    Worksheets("Service Application Paper").Shapes("TextBox 21").TextFrame2.TextRange = _
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4").Value
End Sub

